# Java Defining String constants with same variable name and value

Tags: java, string, constants

Most of the times, I define as

```
public static final String PROCESS_ID ="PROCESS_ID";
public static final String CONTRACT_ID ="CONTRACT_ID";

//It ends up doing lot like this
public static final String VARIABLE_NAME ="VARIABLE_NAME";
public static final String OTHER_NAME ="OTHER_NAME";
```

What is the good practice to get rid of this?
Code review always says that "dont hardcode , use constants"

Is enum better way?

Comment: Why not use `final`?

Comment: 2 problems with making these an enum: 1) You have to explicitly convert to a `String` to use them where you currently use a `String`; 2) You may end up with unrelated "constants" in the same enum; or lots of enums.

Comment: @AndyTurner ,it doesnt look cool defining these kind of string across the project.Looking for any alternate way to do this.

Comment: It's not clear why you would do this in the first place or what kind of problem it is intended to solve. It made more sense before your edit. No sense now.

Comment: put all of them in a single class...

Comment: What are these constants? Are the values? Are they field names? You want constants (among others) so that you can change the value in one place when the need arises. But if you have two strings that are both "PROCESS_ID" but unrelated you should not use the same constant as they will change independently. So you should make clear with either the constant name or the class name in which they are defined, what they are to be used for; so if it's, for example, a field name in some message: `MessageFieldNames.PROCESS_ID` or `Message.FIELD_PROCESS_ID`, etc.

Answer (score 0):

a better practice is:

```
public static final ContractualInfo CONTRACT = new ContractualInfo(0, "CONTRACT_ID");

public static final ContractualInfo PROCESS = new ContractualInfo(1, "PROCESS_ID");
```

Comment: Can you explain why you think this is better?

Comment: This will depend on your usecase (why you do this). 
but from an generic point of view if you do:


`new myWorker(CONTRACT) `

is better than 

`new myWorker("CONTRACT_ID")`

just because you can do things like 

`new myWorker("WHATEVERIWANT")`

You are making whoever uses your class will only provide data that makes sense for your class.

Answer (score 0):

Doing this gives you and future developers an easy place to change something that may be used in multiple areas of an application.

For example, table names in DAO. If you define your table names in constants it means a change to a table name will only require a single change rather than updating the table name in multiple locations.

> What is the good practice to get rid of this?

Check your companies coding style guidelines and follow what they want. If you're just coding on your own, decide on your own guidelines and try to follow them consistently.

> Is enum better way?

It can be. If you need to handle these constants in any kind of list, or if each of the constants have other associated constants, an enum may be appropriate. Again, consult your coding guidelines or make some coding guidelines.